# Create Custom exception with symfony fos rest

Tags: fosrestbundle

```
{
    error: {
        code: 500,
        message: "No route found for "GET /api/v1/adf""
    }
}
```

this is the default exception, how can I create a different view? I tried with exception wrapper but it is not working.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a different view"? Do you want to return a html page from a twig template or do you just want to change the content of the JSON error response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom exception with fosrest bundle in symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040832/custom-exception-with-fosrest-bundle-in-symfony2)